# How can I fix "Non-numeric value for argument 'TE'" issue in the metagen function argument (in R)?

Tags: r, statistics, arguments

even if I inserted "A" as "numeric", Rstudio keeps telling me: "Non-numeric value for argument 'TE'" :

```
   my.meta.analysis$A<-as.numeric(my.meta.analysis$A)
class(my.meta.analysis$A)
my.meta.analysis.metagen <- metagen(TE = A,
                           seTE = Calculated.SE,
                           studlab = Study,
                           data = `my.meta.analysis`,
                           sm = "HR",
                           fixed = FALSE,
                           random = TRUE,
                           method.tau = "REML",
                           hakn = TRUE,
                           title = "my.meta.analysis.metagen")
```

Do you know why? How can I fix it? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: `class((my.meta.analysis$A)` is `numeric`, but what is `class(A)`?